# How to properly use a class member function with boost::coroutine?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-coroutine

I'm currently working with `boost::asymmetric_coroutine`. Let's say we have an ordinary function in the global namespace:

```
void foo(boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<int>::push_type & sink)
{
    //do something
    sink(100);
    //do something else
}
```

In that case, we can create and execute a coroutine using this function in the following manner:

```
boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<void>::pull_type coro{foo};
```

What I need to do is to use a class member function the same way. As I understand it, `boost::bind` should be used somehow, however, the following code doesn't work:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void create_coro()
    {
        boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<int>::pull_type coro
        {
            boost::bind(&MyClass::foo, _1);
        };
    }

private:
    void foo(boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<int>::push_type & sink)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The error it raises is

> no matching function to call to 'get_pointer(const boost::coroutines::push_coroutine&)'

How do I do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
    boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<int>::pull_type coro
    {
        boost::bind(&MyClass::foo, this, _1);
    };
```

note `this`, since you use member function.

Comment: for future readers who, like me, are looking for a way to use a **different** class member function as a coroutine, here's how: `coroutine<void>::pull_type source{std::bind(&MyClass::my_coroutine, &c, std::placeholders::_1)}`, while `c` is an instance of `MyClass`.